# Outlook thread view drives me mad

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Is there any view to make Outlook conversation view...well.sane? All I need is to group emails by conversations/threads and inside each conversation/thread to view the emails in the order they have been received.

I now view emails as conversations, but inside each conversation total madness is going on. Instead of showing all messages it shows ***some*** of them, but ***not all***!!! When I click on that little triangle it shows more messages, but this time it also includes messages from different folders (including sent) and the messages are grouped in some strange hierarchy, which makes it very hard to follow.

All I need is a simple thread with all messages in the order they have been received. Is there any way to configure it to do so?